# Angular 5 externalize prod passwords

Tags: javascript, angular, production-environment

I have prod and dev environments. Prod env is using user credentials to log in (in the future there will be a technical user but for now we need to pass our credentials). 
I want to be able to send the compiled file to my colleague but without my credentials. Instead of that I would like to have json file with credentials so each of us would have own file eg. in project root or on C:/.

Is there a simply way to externalize data like that? I want to only import the file instead of calling the http to fetch it.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  url: '../assets/vdbs.json',
  token: '',
};
```

I want the token to be placed in another file so I would end with

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  url: '../assets/vdbs.json',
};
```

and separate file eg.

```
token: sometoken,
anotherdata; somedata,
```

or

```
TOKEN = sometoken;
ANOTHER_DATA = somedata;
```

Comment: You don't have a separate DB server, that holds your users ?

Comment: We have backend + db which holds the data but to get access to it we need to authorize with user specific token.